# Android 4.0 Face Recognition Intent?

Tags: android, identity

Android 4.0 now features Face Recognition to [unlock the phone](http://www.nfcworld.com/2011/10/19/310778/android-ice-cream-sandwich-adds-nfc-p2p-and-biometric-security). Is this functionality available as an `INTENT` that other applications can also use for Identification?

Note: I'm not talking about the [Face Detection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html) that is supported in the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new face detection stuff was built into the Camera stack ( Perhaps an oversignt? ) and can be found at [Camera.Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html) -- it appears you start it with [Camera.startFaceDetection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#startFaceDetection%28%29) after [Setting the listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setFaceDetectionListener%28android.hardware.Camera.FaceDetectionListener%29)

I have not done more than look around the API docs, so I don't know if this is all the peices to the puzzle you need, but it should get you started on the right direction.

Comment: No - this just detects the presence of a face in the camera view finder. It has nothing to do with Recognition/Identification of the face. It just detects faces and assigns an arbitrary (and changable id) to the face.

Comment: The idenfitication is made through the differences between the eyes and mouth locations, which are reletively unique among different people, even among different family members. If you're looking for a way to get a face and compare it to the owner, you'll have to dig around in the undocumented APIs when the source is released, otherwise this should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

`face2.equals(face2);`